# Installing MariaDB + Galera via yum fails with "No package MariaDB-Galera-server available"

Tags: centos, mariadb, centos7, galera

I'm spun up a brand new Cento OS 7 virtual machine and I'm following [this tutorial](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/getting-started/binary-packages/rpm/yum/) to install a MariaDB + Galera cluster.

I've added the MariaDB repos as follows:

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
```

then filled it with

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.0/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

Now, I'm supposed to run `sudo yum install MariaDB-Galera-server MariaDB-client galera` to install, **which has worked for me before**, but for some reason, only MariaDB-client and galera are installed this time and I'm getting this surprising message from yum:

```
No package MariaDB-Galera-server available.
```

Any idea why?

Edit:

Comparing the [Fedora](http://yum.mariadb.org/10.0/fedora20-amd64/rpms/), [CentOS](http://yum.mariadb.org/10.0/centos7-amd64/rpms/) and [RedHat](http://yum.mariadb.org/10.0/rhel7-amd64/rpms/) repos, it looks like only the Fedora repo has the package. Is that a deployment mistake?

Answer (score 4):

As per official documentation I quote

> There are no longer separate MariaDB Galera Cluster releases for MariaDB 10.1 and above. Simply download MariaDB (10.1 or above) and configure your cluster as normal.

You won't find the package MariaDB-Galera-server on the repo 10.1

To answer your question since you are using the repo 10.0, i just made a test and notice that the package MariaDB-Galera-server is present on CentOS 7.

[image: Screenshot showing MariaDB-Galera-server]

- I am sure that you did not clean the server from old MySQL or MariaDB packages on the machine.
- Also verify the presence of any libs related to mysql or mariadb.
- Also do a `yum clean all` and try installing it.

Comment: Here is my latest article on it http://tunnelix.com/mariadb-galera-cluster-installation/

Answer (score 0):

As long as newer version considered on CentOS 7. You can just use as below

```
yum -y install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client galera
```